# Type error while passing query string as props to arbitrery component in Next.js 12.4

Tags: next.js, query-string

I newbie in Next.js and I've just started learnig routing and query params. I wanted to pass query params down as props to a component to sort my list based on that params. However, when I got my query string through below code

```
interface Props {
  searchParams: { sortOrder: string };
}

const UsersPage = ({ searchParams: { sortOrder } }: Props) => {
  return (...)
```

and passed it through below code

```
      <UsersTable sortOrder={sortOrder}/>
```

I catch this error

Type '{ sortOrder: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
Property 'sortOrder' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

I caught this error on consol
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sortOrder')
So I tried to set the type of queryParams to string or undefined. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I simply defined the Props interface within the component and made sure to pass props as a parameter to the component function. This ensured that the props were correctly typed and accessible within the component.

I wanted to share this solution with you all in case anyone else runs into a similar issue in their code. Remember, properly defining props interfaces and passing props as parameters is essential for type safety and preventing type errors in your React components.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
**<UsersTable searchParams={{ sortOrder }} />**